# Why importing pyspark in python3 needs superuser access on my linux machine?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, sudo

I installed `pyspark` using `pip3`.
Whenever I try `import pyspark` in `python3` , I get an error:

> ```
> import pyspark
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> ModuleNotFoundError:avinash@avinash-HP-ProBook-445-G1:~$ python3
> Python 3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 13:15:42) 
> [GCC 7.2.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> import pyspark
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'
> ```

On the other hand when I use `sudo python3`, everything works fine!

A similar thing happens in Jupyter notebook also, I have to do `sudo jupyter notebook --allow-root` to import `pyspark`

However, importing other packages like numpy works fine without sudo too, that too installed with `pip3`.

Update: I installed pyspark using `sudo pip3 install pyspark` , I tried uninstalling it and then installing it without sudo i.e. `pip3 install pyspark` but it gives error:

> `Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13]
>   Permission denied:
>   '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark-2.4.0.dist-info'
>   Consider using the --user option or check the permissions.`

Strange thing is, there is no file named '*pyspark-2.4.0.dist-info*' as mentioned in error, in the directory `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark-2.4.0.dist-info`.

I also tried giving permission(777) to the above-mentioned directory.

Comment: It seems you have installed pyspark using `sudo pip3 install pyspark`. try installing it without `sudo`.

Comment: Hi @AliAzG 
I tried that too, but it won't install without sudo 

`Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark-2.4.0.dist-info'
Consider using the --user option or check the permissions.
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on error you get, it seems you are using `Anaconda` on linux. In such a case you have to install `pyspark` using the command below:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyspark
```

Comment: I am getting following error : `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:  /home/avinash/anaconda3/.condatmp`
Am I supose to use it with sudo?

Comment: Yes, I think you have installed Anaconda in superuser mode and now you should install it with `sudo` and also run Anaconda in superuser mode.